# Why I can't change the link_to become link_to remote directly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a link_to like this:

```
<%= link_to 'X', category, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

So, I change it like this:

```
<%=link_to_remote category.name,
            :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete%>
```

it show the confirm box, but after I click "yes", it won't delete the item I want , why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no information about what url you need to go to in your link_to_remote usage. You should also specify something like

```
 :url => delete_category_path(category)
```

in the options hash.

Comment: because this method is calling on the /views/store, it is not calling the /views/categories, so, I have this error occur, how can I add the "delete_category_path"


NoMethodError in Store#manage

Showing app/views/store/manage.html.erb where line #13 raised:

undefined method `delete_category_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x103339308>

Comment: The answer above assumes you have defined category as a resource in your config/routes.rb file. Doing that will add *_path and *_url helper methods, including the `delete_category_path`

Comment: thanks Ben
also you can always use the :url => { :action => "...", :controller => "..." } form